# Program a 'Back' button to return to the previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am very new to all this so please be kind. I have searched and read a lot but I'm totally confused.
I have a number of activities say 1 thru to 10. I can go to activity 4 from both activity 3 and 8. However my 'Back' button on activity 4 always returns me to activity 3. I want it to take me back to the previous activity (3 or 8), please.

Here is the current java code:

```
public class Player_new extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_4_new);
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    }
public void sendBackMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, 3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

TIA
John

Comment: To return to the previous `Activity`, just call `finish()`. Do not call `startActivity()`.

Answer (score -1):

Activity A:
startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class);

In activity B

```js
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: This answer is completely useless and therefore confusing to any beginner who reads it. You do not need to override `onBackPressed()` because the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` already calls `finish()`. This is standard Android behaviour. You don't need to do anything at all!